# Retrieve a specific row in a ODBC query in PHP

Tags: php, odbc

I have a result set from an ODBC query. It returned, let's say 500 records. It has a unique field.
I would like to retrieve the value of a specific record, for example the row 348, of that record set.

I end up with

```
$value = odbc_fetch_row($rs, $rownumber);
```

which returns 1 so it finds the record. But I can't find how to get the field value of that record.

Comment: $value=odbc_result($rs,348);

Comment: Sorry, but this does not return any result. 
As far as I know `odbc_result` takes ($result_set, field) as parameters. I also tried $value from `odbc_fetch_row`as data_source, but it does not work either.